# Не срабатывает callback-функция в node.js (не видит загруженный файл)

Tags: node.js, post, express, callback, multer

Я сделал модуль для создания 3 копий изображения разной ширины makeThumbs:

```
sharp = require('sharp');

module.exports = {
    makeThumbs: function (photos) {
        let photo = photos[0];
        let destination = '.' + photo.destination;
        let filename = photo.filename;
        let url = destination + '/' + filename;
        let sizePx = [1280,640,320];
        let sizeNm = ['-l','-m','-s'];

        makeThumb = function(url, sizePx, sizeNm) {
            let extension = url.substr(-4,4);
            let filename = url.substr(0, url.length-4);
            sharp(url)
                .resize(sizePx)
                .toFile(filename + sizeNm + extension, (err, info) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log(info);
                });
            return filename.substr(1) + sizeNm + extension; 
        }

        function makeAllThumbs() {
            let pathToThumbs = [];
            for (let i=0;i<sizePx.length;i++) {
                let newPath = makeThumb(url, sizePx[i], sizeNm[i]);
                pathToThumbs.push(newPath);
            }
            return pathToThumbs;
        }

        let thumbs = makeAllThumbs();
        photo.thumbs = thumbs;
        return photo;
    }
}
```

При тестировании подаю photos на вход функции (отмечу, что такая фотография уже загружена и находится в нужной директории):

```
const mkThumbs = require('./make-thumbs');

let photos = [ { fieldname: 'photo',
originalname: '5qpFr5urfr0.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
destination: './dist/uploads/Dddd',
filename: 'photo-1510260181295.jpg',
path: 'dist/uploads/Dddd/photo-1510260181295.jpg',
size: 213997,
albumtitle: 'Dddd' } ];

mkThumbs.makeThumbs(photos);
console.log(photos);
```

Результат положительный, создаётся 3 копии фото разных размеров с разными окончаниями в именах.
Теперь, в чём **проблема**.
Загружаю фото на сервер, используя мультер в качестве middleware и функцию-коллбек для создания 3 копий загруженного изображения:

```
router.post('/new/:albumtitle', function (req, res, next) {
    let storageForPhotosInAlbums = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, callback) {
            let photoInAlbumsDIR = './dist/uploads/' + req.params.albumtitle;
            callback(null, photoInAlbumsDIR);  
        },
        filename: function(req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })
    let upload = multer({ storage: storageForPhotosInAlbums }).array("photo", 40);
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            sendError(err, res);
        } 
        next();
    });
}, function (req,res) {
    let photo = req.files;
    photo[0].albumtitle = req.params.albumtitle;
    mkThumbs.makeThumbs(photo);
});
```

Фото загружается на сервер в нужную директорию, но в коллбеке файл по этому пути ещё не существует и поэтому выскакивает ошибка "Файл по указанному пути не существует".
Я пробовал разные варианты: ставил setTimeout, фото загружалось, я это видел, но (!) функция-коллбек всё равно выписывала эту ошибку.
Буду рад помощи)

Comment: Я нашёл решение проблемы!) Функция срабатывает, проблема в путях: в тесте я использовал относительный путь, поэтому прибавлял точку к объявлению пути. let destination = '.' + photo.destination; А в сервере я использую path, который использует путь от корня сервера.

Comment: Решение такое:
let destination = photo.destination;

Извините за введение в заблуждение)